# How to use mgo $sum operator

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

My code:

```
func (db *MongoConn) Sum(collection string, query Query, field string) (float64, error) {
queryResult := db.Session.
    DB(db.DialInfo.Database).
    C(collection).
    Pipe([]bson.M{{"$sum": field}})}
```

Error: exception: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$sum'ERROR

Comment: `$sum` is not a stage. That's correct. How would your aggregation look on the shell?